# Correctly Optimizing Redis for memory ussage

Tags: redis

I'm a but of a newbie to systems admin & redis configuration and am trying to figure our how to optimize redis.

We are running a Magento eCommerce app on an AWS m3.large EC2 instance with redis and the backend caching seems quote slow. Up to 15 seconds for TTFB on some pages.

The Root device type of our ec2 instance is ebs.

When I look at the info command output from the redis CLI I see:

```
# Memory
used_memory:16419952
used_memory_human:15.66M
used_memory_rss:23752704
used_memory_peak:25184224
used_memory_peak_human:24.02M
used_memory_lua:33792
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.45
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.4.1
```

And the HTOP command shows:
[image]

Comment: Is there an actual problem with Redis? What's the desired end-state ?

Comment: Why are you looking at redis at all? Shouldn't you be looking for the cause of your 15 second TTFB?